# Live collection strange behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

Why li element are still in the live collection, event though they are not in the DOM?

```js
'use strict';

let lis = document.body.firstElementChild.getElementsByClassName('li');

document.body.firstElementChild.remove();

console.log( lis.length );
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="li"></li>
    <li class="li"></li>
    <li class="li"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The collection is of descendants of the `document.body.firstElementChild`, so even if that element doesn't exist in the DOM anymore, the element *still exists*, and has children that match that class name.

To break the connection, you would have to remove the `.li`s from the `ul`. (Removing the `ul` from the document doesn't break the connection between the `ul` and its `li`s)

```js
const lis = document.body.firstElementChild.getElementsByClassName('li');
document.querySelector('li').remove();
console.log(lis.length);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li"></li>
  <li class="li"></li>
  <li class="li"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I ve read the spec and finally got it. After we create the live collection, the variable lis contains the root element ( ul ) and the filter ( getElementsByClassName('li') ). And every time we call lis, the search is done from the saved root using filter.